# Vertically align two items and one item with multi-line text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have 2 items next to each other. They need to be vertically centered and the second item needs to wrap text if it is too long.

Here is a JS Fiddle of what I have tried: https://jsfiddle.net/zhu0gq2x/

```css
#column-content {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="column-content">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WxW4B.png">
  <span><strong>1234</strong> yet another text content that should be centered vertically</span>
</div>
```

The above example drops the text to a new line if screen gets too small and then starts wrapping it. How do I ensure it stays on the same line? HTML is not set in stone and I can change it to however I need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using flexbox

```
#column-content {
  display: flex; /*or inline-flex*/
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
#column-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="column-content">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cucka.png">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The image on the left does not appear to stay centered. The image itself can be text. As its a letter in real environment.

Comment: That is from the image itself - http://i.imgur.com/WxW4B.png compare the size of space around it. I updated it with another image.

Comment: This seems to be the solution to your issue

Answer (score 2):

CSS Grid can do that:

```css
#column-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

#column-content * {
  align-self: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="column-content">
  <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/50/50">
  <span><strong>1234</strong>
        yet another text content that should be centered vertically</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="column-content" style="white-space:nowrap;">
```

if you use this. it don't create a new line

Comment: That makes the whole thing scroll, not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[CodePen URL](https://codepen.io/manoj854/pen/PEvajB)

```css
#column-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40em;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 100px;
}

#column-content>* {
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<div id="column-content">
  <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WxW4B.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```